# short_open_tag does not work from php.ini (PHP 5.3.26)

Tags: php

I am in the final stages of getting my php projects working locally on Mac OSX Mountain Lion. After struggling for nearly a day getting MAMP to run, setting the right permissions everywhere, setting up a symbolic link to the seemingly elusive mysql.sock, and a whole lot more, it seems I'm nearly there. A few of the projects I'm running make heavy use of the shorthand `<? ?>` tags, and while I know this is advised against, I don't really have a choice.

I checked the location of the used php.ini with `phpinfo()`, and set `short_open_tag` to On, as well as asp style tags. I've restarted MAMP several times already, but still to no avail.
The `phpinfo()` output:

> ```
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc
> Loaded Configuration File         /private/etc/php.ini
> ```

I changed short_open_tag to On in both /etc/php.ini and /private/etc/php.ini.

In the end, I put `php_value short_open_tag 1` in my .htaccess file, and now it works fine. I'm really confused as to why it does not work when I set it in the ini though. Could anyone explain?

Comment: quick hint: on OS X /etc is a symbolic link to /private/etc. So /etc/php.ini and /private/etc/php.ini are the same file.

Comment: Maybe the answer is here : http://serverfault.com/questions/311892/allow-using-php-value-and-php-flag-in-htaccess